# Is it possible to attach and embed a small video inside an email sent with outlook 2016?

Tags: outlook-2016

I want to send an email with a video embed as part of the message body, in the same was that an image could be embed in between the body text, not merely as an attached file.

My employer only uses outlook 2016 and no internet access is reliably available.

The video, which is between 500kB and 1MB can be sent within the 20MB email size limit of our server.

The video is part of a microscope recording and a moving light highlights a critical damage on an expensive part. It is very hard to convey the depth of the damage without the movement of the light.

There is also no intranet server which can host the file.

I could add the video file as an attachment, but that is really not the same as watching it while reading it.

I considered turning the video file into a gif, but it seems that outlook 2016 will not play gifs.
I suppose this is because microsoft deems gifs unappropriate for serious business email or something.